# Include Javascript using Grails asset plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, grails, assets

In my Grails application I'm using the Grails asset plugin, and I'd like it to include a jQuery UI library from a CDN, but only one pages which use jQuery UI. So, I don't want to include jQuery UI in every page, but only on some.

To do this, I tried including the Javascript library in the head of the page, like this:

`index.gsp`

```
<head>
    <meta name="layout" content="main">
    <asset:javascript src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.min.js"/>
</head>
```

`main.gsp`

```
<head>
    <title><g:layoutTitle default="Grails"/></title>
    <asset:stylesheet src="application.css"/>
    <g:layoutHead/>
</head>

<body>
    <asset:javascript src="application.js"/>
    <asset:deferredScripts />
</body>
```

But the CDN jquery UI is not rendered. When I use

```
<script src="//cdn/jqueryui.js" />
```

in the header, it works, but I don't want the jqueryui library already downloaded in the header; I want it a the bottom of the page because it makes loading pages faster. How do I fix this?

Comment: What is wrong with <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.min.js" /> in the body ... ?